# Неправильное растяжение текста в Horizontal Layout Group

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть объект с компонентом HorizontalLayoutGroup и два, дочерних ему, объекта с компонентами Text.

Я выставил настройки layout так, чтоб дочерние объекты растягивались на весь родительский объект.

Если в одном из дочерних объектов введен длинный текст, так что текст переносится на 2 или 3 строки, а во втором текст очень короткий, то остается много пустого пространства в первом, а второй объект становится сжатым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Можно ли стандартными средствами сделать так, чтоб места хватало первому и второму объекту? Как это реализовать?

Настройки layout и Text приведены ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сделай Text вложенным в какой-нибудь фиксированный пустой объект, тогда все будет ровно